# Returning an awaited value returns a Promise? (es7 async/await)

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

```
const ret = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout( () => resolve('somestring'), 1000));

async function wrapper() {
    let someString = await ret();
    return someString;
}

console.log( wrapper() );
```

It logs `Promise { <pending> }`;
Why does it return a Promise instead of `'somestring'`?

I'm using the Babel ES7 preset to compile this.

Comment: Because it is async function. That's the difference between async and normal function.

Comment: I think you can get the benefits of the async/await from inside a async function. If you `console.log(someString)` inside of the `wrapper()` function or inside of any other `async` function, you will get the `somestring` value.

Comment: @estus Then why does logging `someString` right after awaiting it output the correct value?

Comment: Because you `await` for it. The result of async function execution is always a promise. You can await for it if you're inside another async function or unwrap the result with `.then(...)` if you're not.

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7.

Comment: @FelixKling async/await IS part of ES7

Comment: @Gobliins: no, it’s part of ES2017 (ES8).

Comment: @FelixKling You are correct, i falsely assumed ES2017 == ES7

Comment: The key here is that you can't know if the async method did await (that will resolve the promise) or not! That's why the async method always returns a promise. It may be a resolved promise (and then your await or .then() in your outer function will resolve immediately), or it is not resolved yet. You can't know from just looking at the function interface.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Async functions return promises. In order to do what you want, try something like this

```
wrapper().then(someString => console.log(someString));
```

You can also await on `wrapper()` like other promises from the context of another async function.

```
console.log(await wrapper());
```

Comment: You sure about that 2nd example there? I get syntax errors with that.

Comment: @JakeWilson It must be inside an async function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Examples

Answer (score 2):

if you want your async function to return a value immediatly you can use Promise.resolve(theValue)

```
async waitForSomething() {
    const somevalue = await waitForSomethingElse()
    console.log(somevalue)

    return Promise.resolve(somevalue)
}
```

IMO the async await keywords need one more, resolve

it would be nice to write
    return resolve 'hello'

or just

```
resolve 'hello'
```

Comment: well, in the meantime i have discovered that you can just return a variable from a async method, that does the same thing as calling resolve with the variable

Comment: This is the WRONG answer, "if you want your async function to return a value immediately", async function always promise no matter what.

Comment: `resolve 'hello'` is not even valid JavaScript. I wonder how this answer got upvoted.

Comment: @Bergi right! That was why I also wrote an answer.