# async/await always returns promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm trying async/await functionality. I have such code imitating a request:

```
const getJSON = async () => {
  const request = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ foo: 'bar'}), 2000)
  ));

  const json = await request();
  return json;
}
```

When I use the code in this way

```
console.log(getJSON()); // returns Promise
```

it returns a Promise

but when I call this line of code

```
getJSON().then(json => console.log(json)); // prints { foo: 'bar' }
```

it prints json as expected

Is it possible to use just code like `console.log(getJSON())`? What don't I understand?

Comment: `async/await always returns promise` - that is correct, in that all functions tagged `async` will **always** return a Promise - that's the whole point of async/await

Comment: `console.log(await getJSON());`

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**Every `async` function returns a `Promise` object**. The `await` statement operates on a `Promise`, waiting until the `Promise` `resolve`s or `reject`s.

So no, you can't do `console.log` on the result of an async function directly, even if you use `await`. Using `await` will make your function wait and then return a `Promise` which resolves immediately, but it won't unwrap the `Promise` for you. You still need to unwrap the `Promise`  returned by the `async` function, either using `await` or using `.then()`.

When you use `.then()` instead of `console.log`ging directly, the `.then()` method makes the result of the Promise available to you. But you can't get the result of the `Promise` from *outside* the Promise. That's part of the model of working with Promises.

Comment: I thought the whole point of async/await was so that you could write async Promise functions using synchronous code. Are you saying that you always have to follow up an `async` function with `.then()`? If so, then how is that different than just using a Promise by itself?

Comment: The point is that _within_  the `async` function, you can write async code as if it were synchronous. However, from _outside_ the `async` function, you need to treat the asynchronous result of that function as usual. Which is usually not a problem, since you should be only getting asynchronous results in your UI logic anyway.

Comment: In summary: You write your async logic as if it were synchronous, however when you call your async logic from code that is _actually_ synchronous, you need to differentiate between actually-synchronous and actually-asynchronous.

Comment: The extra comments were not needed. The missing element was that await simply unpacks the promise in the same way that .then() does, but what is returned is again wrapped in a promise. And that further means that all the return new Promise syntactic sugar is handled for you, so making a function async does that for you for free and you need only throw errors now and use try / catch to catch rejects or thrown errors (same thing). It all makes so much sense now, so thanks a million!

Comment: "Using `await` will make your function wait and then return a Promise which resolves immediately, but it won't unwrap the Promise for you." Won't it only resolve immediately if the function being `await`ed could be immediately evaluated? Like in OP's example, the promise doesn't resolve immediately as it takes 2 seconds.

Comment: "Won't it only resolve immediately if the function being awaited could be immediately evaluated? Like in OP's example, the promise doesn't resolve immediately as it takes 2 seconds."

That's what's so confusing about this answer. It's obviously not immediate, it'll take two seconds to resolve due to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 6):

**A function defined with `async` always returns a `Promise`. If you return any other value that is not a `Promise`, it will be implicitly wrapped in a `Promise`.**  The statement `const json = await request();` unwraps the `Promise` returned by `request()` to a plain object `{ foo: 'bar' }`. This is then wrapped in a `Promise` before being returned from `getJSON` so a `Promise` is what you ultimately get when you call `getJSON()`. So to unwrap it, you can either call `getJSON().then()` like you've done or do `await getJSON()` to get the resolved value.

Comment: so many warpping and unwrapping IMHO, if you make your answer shorter, it sounds promising

Comment: IKR, I guess the main takeaway is that the return value of an async function is always a promise and must therefore be used with await/then to get the resolved value.

Answer (score 5):

[Return value of an async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value) will always be an [AsyncFunction Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction), which will return a `Promise` when called. You can not change that return type. The point of `async/await` is to easily wait for other async process to complete inside an async function.

Comment: Your first sentence is contradictory, it can't return both a Promise and an `AsyncFunction` object.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, when you define an async function, it will return a `AsyncFunction Object`, which will return a `Promise Object` **when called**. Take `const t = async () => { ... }` for example, `t` is an  `AsyncFunction Object` and `t()` will return a `Promise Object`

Comment: Right my point is the wording is confusing, there is no return, it just evaluates to a value that is an `AsyncFunction` and that function has a return.  `async function fn(){}` is a declaration, it doesn't return anything, it just _is_ an AsyncFunction.

Comment: Do I need to explictly return  for async method?how it will if i dont return anything in async method

Answer (score -1):

```
const getResOrErr = () => {
  const callAsyncCodeHere = async () => {
  const request = () =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        setTimeout(() => resolve({ foo: "bar" }), 2000)
      );

    const json = await request();
    return json;
  };
  return callAsyncCodeHere()
   .then(console.log)
   .catch(console.log);
};

getResOrErr();
```

Try this. You can achieve making a function inside your main function and then put you promise code inside that function. Call it there and when you get the response or error just return it.

Answer (score -1):

Other answers already explain "Every async function returns a Promise object" but I guess the confusion may also come from the fact that you always need to write `await` **twice**, one inside the async function implementation (`getJSON()` in your case) and one for the caller of that async function.

This is a common point of confusion, e.g. [Why do I have to call await twice in order to get the promise resolved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65507527/why-do-i-have-to-call-await-twice-in-order-to-get-the-promise-resolved)

Except for the return value is a promise, [Control flow effects of await in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#control_flow_effects_of_await) can further explain,

> When an await is encountered in code (either in an async function or
> in a module), the awaited expression is executed, while all code that
> depends on the expression's value is paused and pushed into the
> microtask queue. The main thread is then freed for the next task in
> the event loop. This happens even if the awaited value is an
> already-resolved promise or not a promise.

Because "all code that depends on the expression's value (inside the async function) is paused and pushed into the microtask queue", the caller of the async function also needs to **await** (to get the awaited result in the async function).

BTW, one answer here said "if you want your async function to return a value immediately you can use Promise.resolve" is **wrong** in [Returning an awaited value returns a Promise? (es7 async/await)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812505/returning-an-awaited-value-returns-a-promise-es7-async-await) even though it got some upvotes.