# Nodejs async function prototype chain error

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, prototype

why this code compiles

```
var Person =  function() {
console.log("CALLED PERSON")};

Person.prototype.saySomething = function() {
console.log("saySomething PERSON")};

var ape = new Person();
ape.saySomething();
```

and this code throws error Cannot set property 'saySomething' of undefined

```
var Person =  async function() {
console.log("CALLED PERSON")};

Person.prototype.saySomething = function() {
console.log("saySomething PERSON")};

var ape = new Person();
ape.saySomething();
```

Comment: because `(async function () {}).constructor.name !== (function () {}).constructor.name`

Comment: Do not EVER make a constructor `async`.  It will return a promise, NOT a new object.

Comment: Thank's for replying, Why 'AsyncFunction' cannot be added to object prototype while 'Function' ((function () {}).constructor.name)  can be added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `async function() {}`, you are declaring an `asynchronous function` object.   That's different than a regular `function` object.  The asynchronous function object does not have a prototype.

So, when you try to do this:

```
var Person =  async function() {
  console.log("CALLED PERSON")
};

Person.prototype.saySomething = function() {
  console.log("saySomething PERSON")
};
```

`Person.prototype` is `undefined` because there is no `prototype` on an `asynchronous function` object.  Thus attempting to assign something to `Person.prototype.saySomething` causes the error you see because `Person.prototype` is `undefined`.

There is some logic to this because an asynchronous function can't be used as a constructor because an asynchronous function always returns a promise so it can't ever return a new object as in `let obj = new f()`.  So, there's no purpose in having a `.prototype` property because it can't be used that way.

If you really wanted to asynchronously create an object, you could always create an `async` factory function that returns a promise that resolves with an object.

Comment: " an asynchronous function always returns a promise" explain every thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422932/async-await-always-returns-promise

Comment: How abt this?

var Person = function() {
  console.log("CALLED PERSON")
};

Person.prototype.saySomething = async function() {
  console.log("saySomething PERSON")
};

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add an async function **in the end** of the prototype chain.

Please notice that this works well in nodejs 8.11.1+.

```
// lets start with defining some cool async function who takes the time and 
// awaits a promise 

async function someCoolAsyncFunction() {
    // this let will be returned after timeout in a different value.
    let coolStuff = 'still boring';

    // do something cool which takes time 
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
        coolStuff = 'an epiphany';
        resolve();
    }, 1000))
    return coolStuff;
}

// Now let's define the 'regular' prototype chain with it's boring functions.

function Person(p) { 
     this.constructorPropery = p;
     return this;
}

Person.prototype.notAsync = function() {
     // do something regular in the prototype chain
     console.log("Let's build some ",this.constructorPropery)
     this.kindOfPerson = 'Regular and boring'; 
     return this;   
}

// And now, lets add an async function to this chain

Person.prototype.someAsyncFunction = async function() {
    // you will still have access to 'this' in this function as long as the
    // previous function in the prototype chain returnes 'this'
    console.log('I used to be someone ',this.kindOfPerson);

    // Now, this is our time to shine, lets await something cool
    this.lifeChangingEvent = await someCoolAsyncFunction();
    console.log('Until I had ',this.lifeChangingEvent);
    a.kindOfPerson = 'enlightened';
    console.log('and now I am ', a.kindOfPerson);
    return this;
}
```

So this will work:

```
new Person('charachter').notAsync().someAsyncFunction();
```

But this **WILL NOT** work:

```
new Person('charachter').someAsyncFunction().notAsync();
```

And if you really need the data in 'this' outside the prototype chain you can also do:

```
let myself = new Person('charachter').notAsync();
console.log('myself.kindOfPerson is: ',myself.kindOfPerson);
myself.someAsyncFunction(); 
console.log('myself.kindOfPerson now is: ',myself.kindOfPerson);
```

Be sure to remember which prototype is an async function for which function or use your own naming convection for that.

Comment: will this work?
 await new Person('charachter').someAsyncFunction();