# undefined this in async prototype function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, prototype

my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205519/nodejs-async-function-prototype-chain-error). But I want to put async keyword to a prototype function, not to a constructor.

"this" is undefined in the prototype function saySomething. Why? How can I use async in class?

```js
var Person =  function() {
  console.log("CALLED PERSON")
};

Person.prototype.saySomething = async () => {
  console.log(this);//undefined
};

(async function(){
  var ape = new Person();
  await ape.saySomething();
}());
```

Comment: Your losing "this" of the class because your using arrow functions, use normal function

Comment: You could also switch to using `class` syntax which would make this a lot neater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (because it doesn't have own bindings to the `this`) but a [regular function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

```js
var Person =  function() {
  console.log("CALLED PERSON")
};

Person.prototype.saySomething = async function() {
  console.log(this);
};

(async function(){
  var ape = new Person();
  await ape.saySomething();
}());
```

Or another example using [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) (as suggested by @nickf):

```js
class Person {
  constructor() {
    console.log("CALLED PERSON")
  }
  
  async saySomething() {
    console.log(this);
  };
}

(async function(){
  var ape = new Person();
  await ape.saySomething();
}());
```