# Async/await with Express returns Promise { <pending> }

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I'm trying to use async/await function following some tutorials but I don't know why always returns

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Here is my code:

```
function doubleAfter2Seconds(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(x);
            resolve(x * 2);
        }, 2000);
    });
}
async function get_media_async (media_id) {
    const a = await doubleAfter2Seconds(10);
    return a;
}


exports.get_media = function(media_id){
    var media_url = get_media_async(media_id);
    return media_url;
};
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `async/await` won't magically turn async code into sync one. Once you have something async everything it touches becomes async as well. So your `get_media` function is also async.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async/await always returns promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422932/async-await-always-returns-promise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do async/await on `get_media` method as  well. It is because you are calling an `async` function `get_media_async` from within this method thus this needs to be async as well.

```
exports.get_media = async function(media_id){
    var media_url = await get_media_async(media_id);
    return media_url;
};
```