# Webdriverio wait until visible

Tags: async-await, webdriver-io

I'm using webdriverio and need to wait for an element to be in the viewport

So I tried

```
browser.waitUntil(async () => {
    const b = await link.isDisplayedInViewport()
    return b;
}, 5000, 'expected to be visible after 5s');
```

But somehow `waitUntil` wants a boolean not a `Promise<boolean>`

[image]

How can I fix this?

Update:

I use WebdriverIO in a NodeJs app as follows

```
const { remote } = require('webdriverio');

(async () => {
    const browser = await remote({
        logLevel: 'error',
        path: '/',
        capabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    });

    await browser.url('https://example.com');

    const link = await browser.$('.special-link');
    const ok = await browser.waitUntil(async () => {
        const b = await link.isDisplayedInViewport()
        return b;
    }, 5000, 'expected to be visible after 5s');

    await link.click();

    const title = await browser.getTitle();
    console.log('Title was: ' + title);

    await browser.deleteSession();
})().catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

[source](https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted.html)

In the [options](https://webdriver.io/docs/options.html) is don't see anything about with or without async/await. Furthermore I don't use a testing framework!

Comment: Are you running the WDIO in standalone mode? or with WDIO-Runner(with inbuilt sync feature enabled)? The understanding is, it takes the callback as the first param and that callback should return a boolean. So give a try without `async/await` once.

Comment: I've updated my post to show how I use it. Is it possible to do it without async/await in this situation?

Comment: What is the error message you're seeing?

Comment: @KevinLamping I've added a screenshot with the message

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri I am not sure you already tried the `.then .. .catch` approach instead of `async/await` but if not could you please try once. Some reference why i am asking you to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422932/async-await-always-returns-promise

Comment: The error comes because you're returning a `promise` or the result of a promise to `waitUntil`, which a function that accepts in input <a function returning a boolean>. I think the @Balachander answer is a nice way to avoid the issue

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer. But if you are still looking for a solution, Please try this if you want to avoid aync/await

> ```
>  get link() { return browser.element('.special-link'); }
>
>  browser.waitUntil(() => this.link.isVisibleWithinViewport(), 20000, 'link not visible')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
const elementWaitingToBeDisplayed = $("some element locators")
elementWaitingToBeDisplayed.waitForDisplayed(10000, false)
```

If you set the second argument of `elementWaitingToBeDisplayed.waitForDisplayed` to  `true` it waits for the opposite.