# How to use middleware with router.verb() in koa

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa.js

I'm using Koa.js and I was wondering how I could use a middleware with `router.verb()`
As mentioned here [router.use([path], middleware)](https://github.com/ZijianHe/koa-router#module_koa-router--Router+use) I tried like below.
The `console.log()` trigger but the `users.list` is not called

My main objective is to do an auth middleware

```js
const Router = require("@koa/router");
const router = new Router();
const users = require("./Controllers/users/index.js");

router.use("/user", (ctx, next) => {
    console.log(ctx);
    next();
});

router.get("/user", users.list)
```

I don't get any error messages but the `users.list` don't execute.

Then i tried this

```js
router.get("/user", (ctx, next) => {
    console.log(ctx);
    next();
}, users.list)
```

But i don't get any change and I feel like I don't understand something, but can't figure out what

In my index.js

```js
const Koa = require("koa");
const router = require("./Routes");
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");
const cors = require("@koa/cors");
const serve = require("koa-static");
const path = require("path");

const errorHandler = require("./Middlewares/errorHandler");
const app = new Koa();

app.use(errorHandler)
    .use(bodyParser())
    .use(cors())
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(serve(path.join("public", "ads")))
    .use(router.allowedMethods());
```

in my controller

```js
const { Users } = require("../../Models");

module.exports = {
    list: async (ctx, next) => {
        let AllUsers = await Users.findAll();
        ctx.body = AllUsers;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with the router after adding your routes

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Try editing your question and add it there, and also the source for the `list` method

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with adding `await next()`

```js
router.use("/ads", async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log(ctx);
    await next();
});
```

Since my controller is an async function I get my explanations from here -> [async/await always returns promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422932/async-await-always-returns-promise)