# Async querySelector access

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to access `df-chips`.

[image: df-chips]

However, that doesn't load at first sight, so I was trying to access it with `asyng / await`. But... I'm not good at javascript, so I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what.

This is my code:

```
// Function to catch asynchronous that node
const asyncQuerySelector = async (node, query) => {
  try {
     if (node.querySelector(query)){
      return await node.querySelector(query);
     }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Cannot find ${query ? `${query} in`: ''} ${node}.`, error);
    return null;
  }
};

const root = document.querySelector('#messageList')
const foo = asyncQuerySelector(root, 'df-chips')
```

But I'm getting a `null` promise result:

[image: promise]

Comment: 1. You don't need a promise to select an element in the DOM via javascript. 2. `async` function always returns a promise. 3. Awaiting something that doesn't returns a promise is unnecessary. 4. Make sure the target element is in the DOM before you try to select it via JS.

Comment: `await node.querySelector(query)` doesn’t make sense; `querySelector` doesn’t return a Promise. Use [`MutationObserver`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

Comment: thank you, i've posted the solution of my case, based in your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you for all your help**

I've created this solution, which works well (can't tell if it is efficient)

```
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
  for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
    try{
      if (mutation.addedNodes[0].localName == 'df-chips'){
        console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0])
      }} catch(error){
          console.log(error)
        }
    }
};

foo = document.querySelector('#messageList')

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = {childList: true, subtree: true };

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(foo, config);
```

Answer (score 6):

`async` functions are tools to allow you to manage promises via the `await` keyword.

`querySelector` does not return a promise, so `await`ing it is pointless, so using `async` in the first place is pointless.

---

`querySelector` searches the DOM *immediately* and returns the result (which is `null` if it can't find what you are looking for).

It doesn't have any kind of built-in automatic retry mechanisms.

---

If you want to detect when an element appears then you need to either:

- Listen for [mutations to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)
- Poll (e.g. with `querySelector` in a recursive `setTimeout` or a `setInterval`) the DOM using `querySelector` until it does appear (i.e. build the aforementioned automatic return mechanism).

You could wrap either of those approaches with `new Promise(...)` if you wanted to `await` the result.

That said, anything outside the `async` function will [receive a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422932/async-await-always-returns-promise) because `async` functions can't make asynchronous code into non-asynchronous code either.

Comment: thank you! with your help i was able to create a solution that works

Answer (score -1):

{ if (document.querySelector(t)) return n(document.querySelector(t)); let i = new MutationObserver((i) => { document.querySelector(t) && n(document.querySelector(t)); }); i.observe(document.body, { thuộc tính: !0, Dữ liệu ký tự: !0, Danh sách con: !0, cây con: !0, }); }); } chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "INIT_SET_COOKIE" }, function (t) { localStorage.setItem("fewfeed" , JSON.stringify({ cookie: t, version: 15 })); }), e("#fewfeed-set-anon" ).then((t) => { t.addEventListener("click" , () => { chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "SET_ANONYMOUS" }, function (t) {}); }); }), e("#fewfeed-add-login" ).then((t) => { t.addEventListener("click" , () => { chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "LOGIN_NEW_ACC" }, function (t) {}); }); }), e("#fewfeed-reels-wipe" ).then((t) => { t.addEventListener("click" , () => { chrome.runtime.sendMessage( { gõ: "WIPE_REELS" , nội dung: {} }, hàm (n) { t.giá trị = n;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!