# RxJs resolve promise and return observable

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I would like to return an observable from a function but I need to resolve a promise before.

```js
async getData(path: string): Observable<Data> {
    
    // getInfo is asynchronous
    let appInfo = await App.getInfo();
    
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Test': appInfo.name});

    return this.http.get<Data>(environment.url + path, {headers: headers});
}
```

But actually this is not working because of `async` keyword which returns a `Promise`: the return of this function is `Promise<Observable<data>>`.

How can I get data from the asynchronous call and the return the obervable from `http.get`?

EDIT: this was closed linking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422932/async-await-always-returns-promise) but I already know that an async function returns a Promise. I would like to know how to use [RxJs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview) to avoid `async` and therefore return an `Observable`.

Comment: I would like to answer this question. But it's closed so I voted to reopen:

In RxJS 6 and below you can call `toPromise()` if you are using RxJS 7 and above you can just `return await firstValueFrom(http.get(...))`

Comment: You can convert the promise to observable using `from`: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from
From that, you can `switchMap` to the http call

Comment: Thanks for your responses but someone closed this without thinking on it.. Please vote to reopen

Comment: You may find [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) interesting