# Angular/typescript cant access values set inside promise then/catch

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

Im working on a file upload that is split into chunks. Below is the simplified code. Im trying to save the error captured inside the error block but its value is not saved after the clause. Can you please advise?

```
uploadFile() {
  let id;
  let error;
  for(let chunk in chunks) {
      this.uploadChunk(chunk).
        then(result => { id = result.id}).
        catch(error => { error = error; console.log(error))} --> output the error recieved from the backend
  }

console.log(error);   // this is always null, the error never saved. 
}


async uploadChunk(chunk) {
  return await lastValueFrom(this.http.post(chunkData))
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you - I thought Im solving the issue by having the upload chunk function be async -await?

Comment: The local variable has the same name as the catch function parameter, which leads to ambiguities. Try renaming one of them.

Comment: The problem is, the code that sets the value of id, and error, doesn’t run until long after your attempt at logging it, for the reasons explained at the duplicate. You can similarly use await to make the for loop wait, but I don’t know what the ramifications of that are with angularjs and the method you are working with

Comment: @user1380431 No, `uploadChunk` [still returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43422932/1048572). To solve it you need to make `uploadFile` an `async` function` and use **`await` instead of `.then(…)`**. (You'd also [use `try`/`catch` for error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44663864/1048572) then)